# hexadecimal to binary and decimal in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a txt file which has hexadecimal data. I Want to convert them in decimal except one column which I want to convert into binary bits and write them in 8  separate columns.
Sample data set

> 1/4/2010 15:31 <00000> 0x0001  0x0010  0x0014  0x0000  0x0142  0x0001  0x0001  0x0000  0x028F  0x2007  0x0105  0x00AA  0x005A  0xFA8C  0xFACD  0xFAED  0x003B  0xFFA3  0xFFDE  0x0080  0xFEE0  0xFF2E  0x0000  0x0108
>   1/4/2010 15:31 <00000> 0x0001  0x0010  0x0014  0x0000  0x0143  0x0001  0x0001  0x0000  0x028F  0x2008  0x0105  0x00AA  0x005B  0xFA8C  0xFACC  0xFAEE  0x003C  0xFFA3  0xFFDE  0x0080  0xFEE0  0xFF2E  0x0000  0x0108
>   1/4/2010 15:31 <00000> 0x0001  0x0010  0x0014  0x0000  0x0144  0x0001  0x0001  0x0000  0x028F  0x2009  0x0105  0x00A9  0x005C  0xFA8C  0xFACC  0xFAF0  0x003B  0xFFA3

clear all;
%

> [b,pathb]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the file','C:\Data\2010');
>
> file2=[pathb b];
>
> data=dlmread('file2', '\t', 2, 1);
>
> newdata=hex2dec(data);

Now I  do not know how to get rid of  0x in all the values and I need to convert the last column into binary and write in  8 columns.

Any help  is highly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different tack you could try, using [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) to read all the data first as strings:

```
fid = fopen(file2,'rt');                   %# Open the file
str = ['%s %s %s ' repmat('0x%s ',1,24)];  %# Format string for columns
C = textscan(fid,str,'CollectOutput',1);   %# Read all fields as strings
                                           %#   (removing 0x's)
fclose(fid);                               %# Close the file
C = C{1};                                  %# Remove outer cell encapsulation

dates = strcat(C(:,1),{' '},C(:,2));         %# Collect the date strings
decValues = cellfun(@hex2dec,C(:,4:end-1));  %# Convert the first 23 columns to
                                             %#   decimal values
decValues = decValues-65536.*(decValues > 32767);  %# Change from unsigned to
                                                   %#   signed 16 bit values
binValues = cellfun(@(n) dec2bin(hex2dec(n),8),...    %# Convert the last column
                    C(:,end),'UniformOutput',false);  %#   to binary strings
```

If you have N rows in your file, you should end up with:

- An N-by-1 cell array `dates` of date strings (which can be converted to either [serial date numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) or [date vectors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html)).
- An N-by-23 array `decValues` containing the converted decimal values. The values were converted from the range 0 to 65535 (i.e. unsigned 16-bit integer) to -32768 to 32767 (i.e. signed 16-bit integer) using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement).
- An N-by-1 cell array `binValues` containing the converted binary values. Each cell contains a 1-by-8 character string of zeroes and ones.

Comment: I keep getting this error....[Error in ==> hex2decimal at 6
C = textscan(fid,repmat({'%s '},27));  %# Read the data as strings]        Also is there command to rewrite a new file with Nx34 size as i have  last column converted to 8 binary bits

Comment: @AP: I think I've fixed the bug. Try the new version.

Comment: @AP: I'm not sure what specific format you want for your output file, but generally you can use the function [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html). For each line in the output, you would print `dates` and `<00000>` as strings (`%s` format), then your 23 decimal values (`%d` format), then the 8 characters of your binary number (`%c` format).

Comment: @gnoice.. Another interesting problem, looking at hex decimal FAEE ect i am sure its a negative value. But it has both negative and positive , how do i distinguish them?            I can use  [
>> typecast(uint16(sscanf('FAEE', '%4x')),'int16') ] to get the negative values , but what if that number was positive?

Comment: @AP: I've updated the code. In particular, I simplified the removal of the `0x`'s and added a line that will convert your unsigned 16-bit integer values to signed 16-bit integer values using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement).